# Finding different presentations of a number in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula, ms-office

Let me put this question in this way:

I have a column of data like 3.125,7.9375 etc.

I want to have a column which will be representing values like 3 1/8,7 15/16.So, that while importing it to SQL server I can get values like 3 1/8.

Is there any formula regarding that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

and copy down.  Then format column **B** as *fractions*:

[image]